# Can I lay geotextile sheeting beneath new grass?

Tags: grass, weeds, sod

We have an area of ground that was a thick mix of overgrown weeds and plants. We would like to turf this area. We have turned over the soil and taken out some of the roots but there are still a lot of weed roots in the area.

Can we put down a layer of geotextile to stop the weeds growing through the new turf? Our plan was to lay the geotextile, then cover in top soil and then lay the turf. Is this correct, will it stop the weeds growing through our new grass?

Thanks

Comment: See second paragraph of your previous Q&A https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/49004/laying-grass-on-heavily-rooted-area. If you still feel you want to lay a membrane, it must be a minimum of 6 to 8 inches below the new turf - but it will do very little in terms of weed suppression.

Comment: you will still get weeds from above... you are probably better with solarization or chemical spraying... which wont leave you dealing with fabric pulling up with weed roots later... basically nothing is foolproof...  ie. 4 inches of soil will suppress most common weeds from seed about as well as fabric + 4 inches of soil... and neither is going to stop stuff like field bindweed from finding a way to the surface... or wind blown seeds from starting on the surface.

Comment: Don't use that fabric.  You will regret it later down the road.  Now that you turned the soil it will be hard to use Chemical spray.  You could try putting down a good thick layer of topsoil over what you turned and lay the turf on top of it.  This will suppress most of the weeds.

Comment: Here's a test you can do on your geotextile. Cut a piece large enough to completely cover the lid of a jar of, say, 4"/10cm in diameter plus an additional 2"/5cm. Use a rubber band to firmly attach the textile to the jar (making sort of a drum of the textile and jar). Pour water onto the textile and see how much actually goes through the fabric and into the jar. You will find that for the majority of products in the market, very little water actually goes through the fabric (even those products labelled as promoting good water/gas exchange). Lack of drainage 6" under a lawn is a very bad idea.